# How to draw an arrow with the mouse using KonvaJS?

Tags: javascript, konvajs

community. I need to draw an arrow with the mouse using KonvaJS. I do not use React. It's the first time I use KonvaJS. I have searched information for solving this problem but I found nothing. I also read the documentation of this library but I found only how to draw a basic arrow. I will appreciate your help. Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you post a png image how the arrow will look like?

Comment: @ChrisP Of course. Let me show you exactly what I want to do:

https://codesandbox.io/s/w12qznzx5?file=/src/index.js 

In this link there's a whiteboard that allows you draw arrows. I want to draw arrows like those. My intention is to design  a whiteboard like that without using React.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to draw an arrow. You can follow [Free drawing Konva Demo](https://konvajs.org/docs/react/Free_Drawing.html#page-title), but use arrow instead of a line.

The simplest solution is to use `mousedown` - to create a line, `mousemove` to update line position, `mouseup` - to finish line.

```js
let arrow;
stage.on('mousedown', () => {
   const pos = stage.getPointerPosition();
    arrow = new Konva.Arrow({
      points: [pos.x, pos.y],
      stroke: 'black',
      fill: 'black'
    });
    layer.add(arrow);
    layer.batchDraw();
});

stage.on('mousemove', () => {
  if (arrow) {
      const pos = stage.getPointerPosition();
      const points = [arrow.points()[0], arrow.points()[1], pos.x, pos.y];
      arrow.points(points);
      layer.batchDraw();
  }
});

stage.on('mouseup', () => {
  arrow = null;
});
```

Demo: https://jsbin.com/lefivihibu/2/edit?html,js,output